# How can i merge 2 disk in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I want to use the memory of other disk in my computer by merging the two disk you can see in the image.

[image: Disk Manager]

So the question is how can I merge the 2 disk(disk 0 and disk 1) in to 1 driver only?

Comment: You don’t. While possible, it’s a terrible idea. What is that you really want to achieve? Where is space lacking now? What are you trying to do that requires more space?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial offers 3 different ways to merge 2 disks into one:

- **Option 1**: Use Symbolic Links

  1. Find one of the folders that you want to move to your second drive. In this case, let's say it's *C:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Portal*. Move that folder to your second drive, and note its location (in this case, we'll say it's *D:\Games\Portal*.
  2. Open up a Command Prompt and type the following command: 
     *mklink /J C:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Portal D:\Games\Portal*
  3. If you were creating a hard link to a file instead of a folder, you would use /H instead of /J after the command.
  4. Reopen Steam and try to launch your game. It will look in the old path, find the hard link, and be directed to the game's new location.

You can also use free software like **Link Shell Extension** to perform the same task without the command line.

- **Option 2**: Create a Spanned Volume
- **Option 3**: Set Up a RAID Array

More details: http://lifehacker.com/5986883/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-into-one-volume-for-cheap-high-capacity-storage

Comment: Please provide all relevant steps inside your answer in case the linked page becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create junction link of disk 2 in disk 1 as folder.  for more info check this page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point

A junction point can be created in Vista or later

```
mklink /J <Link> <Target>
```

A junction point can be created in XP (after installing; [Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)) with

```
LINKD Source Destination
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.